# How to use satellite.js in Angular 8 Project

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I want to use SGP4/SDP4 calculations of [satellite.js](https://github.com/shashwatak/satellite-js) library to convert a [TLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-line_element_set) String and finally create a Satellite Orbit map.
 The Question is how can I add this library to my project?
I already installed satellite.js with NPM but still can't access to its methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am only guessing based on my experience (which is not vast), but
`import * as satellite from 'satellite.js'`
should work just fine.